# Filebeat and bufferring

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Sorry, if its a naive question. 
I've Filebeat is configured to ship data to ES directly. Just incase ES is offline and filebeat harvester found a log to ship, would it buffer, retry and ship?

here is what I tried, my docker container generated a log file, filebeat got that log entry and reported saying sent 'x' events but ES wasn't reachable. I deleted the log file thinking that filebeat got it buffered and then started ES. I dont see the logs coming thru.

How to handle this scenario?

Comment: Can you share you filebeat config please?

Comment: check this out https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-and-bufferring/53225

Answer (score 0):

If you want queuing you have to add broker like kafka, redis or rabbitMQ, several configurations are possible, you can also send to logstash will keep data if ES is down... if it is down (ES) go to your log you will see connection refuse no data sent

Comment: Can filebeat send log events to rabbitMQ?

Comment: no you can not ,https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-rabbitmq-plugin/55189/3, becareful filebeat not send same data as logstash